# How to calculate the start and end lat/lon of a linestring which is not a part of a ST_buffer?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I'm trying to find out the lat/lon of points on a linestring that are not contained inside a geometry formed by a `ST_buffer`. I can find if the linestring intersects the geometry but I'm not able to find how can I get the points.

For example. Consider the following image. The substrings of the linestring that are not covered by the polygon are `BC` and `FG`. So, I'm trying to get the lat/lon of the `B,C,F,G` in order. Is it possible to do this in PostGIS ?

UPDATE:

I've written this query so far but it returns more than expected values. Some of them are inside the ST_buffer.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Difference(road::geometry,circle.the_geog::geometry)) FROM (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(85.269150 23.157234,85.278541 23.101098,85.286367 23.047280,85.287737 23.006227)') as road) AS road,towers as circle WHERE ST_Intersects( circle.the_geog,ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(85.269150 23.157234,85.278541 23.101098,85.286367 23.047280,85.287737 23.006227)')
    );
```

UPDATE 2:

I also tried `ST_SymDifference`. Though the results are correct but I'm also getting `POLYGON` in the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`. Also it returns many rows instead of just one.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SymDifference(road::geometry,circle.the_geog::geometry)) 
FROM (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(85.269150 23.157234,85.278541 23.101098,85.286367 23.047280,85.287737 23.006227)') as road) 
AS road,poly as circle WHERE ST_Intersects(circle.the_geog,road);
```

[image]

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37974612/327026)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[ST_Split](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Split.html) will split a line by a multi polygon and return a geometry collection by which you can retreive the lat,long of the start and endpoints.</strike>

This statement:

1. uses some similiar test geometry of 1 multiline and 3 polygon circles:
2. combines the 3 circles into a single geometry with Union All and ST_Union
3. gets the intersected geometry between the line and the combined circles with ST_Intersection
4. simplifies the intersected geometry down to the endpoints with ST_Simplify
5. dumps the simplified points with ST_Dumppoints
6. and finally displays each points Lat,Long with ST_X and ST_Y

> 

```
SELECT (t.d).path,ST_X((t.d).geom),ST_Y((t.d).geom) FROM
 (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(
        ST_Simplify(
        ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LineString (85.26914999999999623 23.15723399999999899, 85.27854100000000415 23.10109800000000035, 85.27991034974166951 23.0916812271406684, 85.28636699999999848 23.04728000000000065, 85.28773700000000701 23.00622699999999909)'),
(SELECT ST_Union(geom )
FROM
(SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((85.27915 23.157234,85.2762210678119 23.1501629321881,85.26915 23.147234,85.2620789321881 23.1501629321881,85.25915 23.157234,85.2620789321881 23.1643050678119,85.26915 23.167234,85.2762210678119 23.1643050678119,85.27915 23.157234))') as geom
        UNION ALL
SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((85.288541 23.101098,85.2856120678119 23.0940269321881,85.278541 23.091098,85.2714699321881 23.0940269321881,85.268541 23.101098,85.2714699321881 23.1081690678119,85.278541 23.111098,85.2856120678119 23.1081690678119,85.288541 23.101098))') as geom
        UNION ALL
SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((85.29 23.09,85.2870710678119 23.0829289321881,85.28 23.08,85.2729289321881 23.0829289321881,85.27 23.09,85.2729289321881 23.0970710678119,85.28 23.1,85.2870710678119 23.0970710678119,85.29 23.09))') as geom ) as three_circles)),3)) as d) as t
```

Comment: `ST_Split` will also split the other circles that are not required. For example the two circles in the figure.

Comment: Updated with new answer